# In_close_write event from python watchdog

Tags: python, watchdog

I'm working on a simple watchdog script that will run md5sum on some very large images uploaded to our FTP.  Watchdog doesn't seem to have a IN_CLOSE_WRITE event which exists in pyinotify.  I tried checking if the file is still open as a work around but that does not work.  Does anyone know a workaround to getting close_write event from watchdog?

```
import sys
import time

from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


path = sys.argv[1]

class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print "File uploaded"
        # Is file still uploading?
        f = open(event.src_path)
        if f.closed:
            print "....run md5 & email admin"


event_handler = MyEventHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently that's not really possible with watchdog. Since watchdog tries to be platform-independent, it only handles events that can be detected on all platforms. There is another question that is relevant:
[Python (Watchdog) - Waiting for file to be created correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118249/python-watchdog-waiting-for-file-to-be-created-correctly)

Also there is a issue on github, which is closed (basically wontfix):
https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/184

So it seems that going with pyinotify is probably the best option.

Comment: I have recently seen a project that uses another approach, by using ctypes to call into libc directly:

https://github.com/uktrade/mobius3/blob/master/mobius3.py#L57


Just found that approach interesting, for me pyinotify worked well.

Comment: A "couple" years later, but it looks like they did add a `on_closed` for linux now (not documented (yet)), for anyone who happens to stumple across this SO post